# Sending form data from php page to email in UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a big problem with form data sending to email. When I fill my order form, in email I get:

**VÄrdiÅ†Å¡: LÄ«va,**

instead of **Vārdiņš: Līva**

I think I have set right utf-8, but nothing changes. Can anyone help?

**Here's my orders.php**

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
//subject and email variables//
$emailSubject = 'Pasūtījums no www.gramatina.lv';
$webMaster = 'info@gramatina.lv';

//gathering data variables//
$type = $_POST['type'];
$typography = $_POST['typography'];
$spiral = $_POST['spiral'];
$color_name = $_POST['color_name'];
$nameYes = $_POST['nameYes'];
$unryu = $_POST['unryu'];
$nameU = $_POST['nameU'];
$shipping = $_POST['shipping'];
$totalPrice = $_POST['totalPrice'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$other_color = $_POST['other_color'];

$body = <<<EOD
Grāmatas veids: $type
Krāsa: $typography, $spiral, $unryu, $other_color
Ar vai bez vārdiņa: $color_name
Vārdiņš: $nameYes, $nameU
Piegādes veids: $shipping
Cena: $totalPrice
Vārds, uzvārds: $first_name, $last_name
E-pasta adrese: $email
Telefona numurs: $telephone
Piegādes adrese: $address
Komentārs: $comments
EOD;

$header = "From: $email";

If($_POST){
    mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $header);
    header('Location: thank_you_order.html');

}
?>
```

**And here's html page heading:**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Mūsu mazuļa grāmatiņa</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <form action="orders.php" method="post">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Consider using this class https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer to send pretty fine emails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mail($webMaster,'=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($emailSubject).'?=', $body, $header_ . $header);
```

Comment: No, this one did't help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add header

> "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"

to your message body.

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

If you use native mail() function $headers array will be the 4th parameter mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)

Comment: when I add it, I don't recieve email.

Comment: does your email service works correct? did you checked?